# Encapsulation of Process creates unexpected behavior

Tags: c++, process, encapsulation

My assignment requires me to encapsulate the principle of process handling.

Here's what my Process class contains:

```
class Process
{
public:
  Process();
  ~Process();

  pid_t getPid() const;

private:
  pid_t         pid_;
};
```

Constructor:

```
Process::Process()
{
  this->pid_ = fork();
}
```

Destructor:

```
Process::~Process()
{
  if (this->pid_ > 0)
    kill(this->pid_, SIGKILL);
}
```

Here's the problem: after encapsulating and creating an object like such:

```
void    example()
{
  Process       pro;

  if (pro.pid_ == 0)
    {
      // Child Process                                                                                                      
    }
  else if (pro.pid_ < 0)
    {
      // Error                                                                                                         
    }
  else
    {
      // Parent Process                                                                                                     
    }
}
```

My program almost never enters the child code, but when I `fork()` normally (with no encapsulation) it works like a charm.

Where did I go wrong? How may I synchronize the child and parent to be sure that they both do their jobs?

Comment: This code cannot possibly compile. `pid_` is private variable that cannot be accessed from example(). Please don't post imaginary make-believe code, but a [mcve], instead. Otherwise your question will be voted down and closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't verify your example but I see an obvious flaw in your class Process. It defines custom constructor and destructor but assignment operator is not defined which violates the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Consider following code:

```
void example()
{
   Process pro;
   {
      Process pro2 = pro;
   }
   // here pro.pid_ will have id of the already killed process
}
```